# SMSS: Failed to decrypt a column encryption key

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, ssms

I have a database with some columns encrypted. the datasource settings are:

```
@Bean(name = "azureLocalDataSource")
public DataSource localDataSource() throws IOException {
    log.debug("Initializing Azure Sql DEV DataSource");
    this.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceUrl);
    this.addDataSourceProperty("columnEncryptionSetting","Enabled");
    this.addDataSourceProperty("keyStoreAuthentication", "JavaKeyStorePassword");
    this.addDataSourceProperty("keyStoreLocation",new ClassPathResource(keyStoreLocation).getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    this.addDataSourceProperty("keyStoreSecret",keyStoreSecret);
    this.addDataSourceProperty("defaultAutoCommit", false);
    this.addDataSourceProperty("trustServerCertificate", true);
    return new HikariDataSource(this);
}
```

when I queried the column in SSMS with "Always Encrypted" on,
SELECT customer_id FROM [schema1].[rewards_points_issuance_recon]

I got the following error:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
Failed to decrypt column 'customer_id'.
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
Failed to decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name: 'MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered) custom key store provider names are: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Please verify key store provider information in column master key definitions in the database, and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are registered properly.
```

Is there anywhere I can specify the keystone location and password?
How can I display the plaintext values of the column in SSMS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-query-columns-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#retrieving-plaintext-values-stored-in-encrypted-columns What does [tag:spring-boot] have to do with this?

Comment: I followed the procedure. I'm logged in as SA user and enabled Always Encrypted option. And I got above error. The data was inserted into the table from spring boot application.

Comment: And have you put the key somewhere on the client? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver16 Loggin in as `sa` is not enough, you need to actually have the key on the client.

Comment: I think SSMS is not aware of the keystore used when writing the data. But I don't know how to configure that in SSMS

Comment: It's all there in the links

Comment: I don't see an example using jks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/configuring-the-client-for-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I am able to write encrypted data into the table using the jks. I want to be able to view the data in plaintext in SSMS

Comment: I'm going round in circles: are you using JKS or SSMS? I've show you the links how to do both. For querying in SSMS, you need to add the key to a relevant key store, either the Windows Certificate Store, or an HSM, or to Azure. This is linked in the first link I gave you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver16 Once you've done that, you can enable Always Encrypted in the settings.

Comment: @Charlieface, i think he wants to use SSMS and get the keys from JKS store :) Suspect that's not possible though

Comment: No probably not. SSMS uses SqlClient under the hood, which I'm pretty sure only connects to Windows Certificate Store. Linux might be different though.